# how to get array of properties from array of objects in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, oop

I am using an array of objects in my program, and each object has several attributes. I want to be able to extract separate arrays from this array of objects, one array for each attribute. 
here is a snippet of the relevant code:

```
dailyDataMatrix(m,n)=dailyData('',''); %creates an mxn array of dailyData objects
for i=1:m
  for j=1:n
  dailyDataMatrix(i,j)=dailyData(datainput1, datainput2)%dailyData constructor, sets attributes
  end
end
dailyDataMatrix.attribute
```

But when I try to access a certain attribute as in the code above, say of type string, I get a strange result. Instead of getting an array of strings, I get something else. When I try to print it, rather than printing an array, it prints a series of individual values

ans = 'string1'
ans = 'string2'
...

When I try to call

```
size(dailyDataMatrix.attribute)
className = class(dailyDataMatrix.attribute)
```

I get
"error using size: too many input arguments" and
"error using class: The CLASS function must be called from a class constructor."

However, when I write this as

```
thing=dailyDataMatrix.attribute
className = class(thing)
size(thing)
```

I get the response 
classname = 'double' and size = 1x1.

Why is this not returning an array the same size as dailyDataMatrix? And an aside question is why the two different ways of writing the code above give different results? and how can I get the result that I want?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Example your your array of objects or its simplified/demo version would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture all the outputs using a cell array or using square brackets if the types are same. For regular array when all values are of same type use,

```
thing=[dailyDataMatrix.attribute];
```

If the types are different you can use

```
thing = cell(1,N); % N is the number of elements in dailyDataMatrix
[thing{:}] = dailyDataMatrix.attribute;
```

Comment: thank you very much, a very simple trick that solves my problem. Could you maybe explain what is going on here in a little more detail? I guess my question is, if dailyDataMatrix.attribute isn't already an array, then what is it?

Comment: also, I just realized that instead of making dailyDataMatrix.attribute into an mxn array, it turns it into a 1xm*n array. but it is easy to correct this with reshape()

Comment: When you access fields of an array of structs it returns a comma separated list. Documentation for this is at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html

Comment: Or in a more compact way: `{dailyDataMatrix.attribute}`
(taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14986845/4892892)